# Github Pages shows blank page when launching a website

Tags: php, github, github-pages

My repo: https://github.com/JainUmang/jainumang.github.io
My website: https://jainumang.github.io /

I can not figure out why my GitHub pages can’t load any of my source files. I want to load the index[dot]php file. Everything works as it should on localhost. It only loads readme. If someone could help me with it. I'm new to this.

Comment: Github pages does not support server-side languages as [stated here](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github is just a repository site there is no deployment or any such server side scripting platform.

You cannot run any server side script on github yaah you may view HTML file.

Try hosting your site/project on some hosting sites like

1. 000webhost
2. heroku etc

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will host it on heroku.

Answer (score 1):

I did not work with [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/), but looking at the documentation, they do not support `PHP` files, as they only support static files. You can use [Markdown or HTML files](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site), or instead, static files can be generated using [Jekyll](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/about-github-pages-and-jekyll).

If you do want to add dynamic functionality, you could probably use an `iframe`. However, anything displayed in that `iframe` should be hosted elsewhere.